# When I update a related contact field with process builder, can I then reference that contact in the same workflow using a time based email?

Tags: process-builder

I'm trying to replace a before insert trigger  with a process builder.  The PB updates a contact field with a contact Id from a related Opportunity.  Can I then email that same Contact in a time base delayed action?

Answer (score 1):

yes 
their ia a checkbox on critera node "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" check it. then you can have Scheduled Actions also.

[image]

n create your time based or intermediate Actions.

[image]